# Alamofire 4 - Cannot call value of non-function type HTTPURLResponse

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm updating my app to Swift 3 and I use Alamofire to handle API call to a REST server. This is my function:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    func responseAllCareers(_ username: String, password: String, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Careers>) -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<Careers> { request, response, data, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!))
            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            guard case let .success(jsonObject) = result else {
                return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
            }

            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                let api: APIMessage = APIMessage(json: value as! JSON)!
                var careers: Careers = Careers()

                // check for correct credentials
                if api.result != "failure" {
                    careers = Careers(json: value as! JSON)
                    CacheManager.sharedInstance.storeCredentials(username, password: password)
                    CacheManager.sharedInstance.storeJsonInCacheByKey(CacheManager.CAREERS, json: value as! JSON)
                    careers.areCredentialsValid = true
                }
                return .success(careers)
            case .failure(let error):
                return .failure(error)
            }
        }
        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
```

I'm getting a **Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse'** error at the last return line and I cannot figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to init a response by using a value instead of a type

```
response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

where actually `response` is an instantiated constant.
The second problem is that the function is supposed to return an `Alamofire.Request` type, not an `HTTPURLResponse` type.